# How prominent should the deactivate account function be?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, buttons, design-patterns

Our app allows users to interact with multiple accounts.  When any one account has outlived it's usefulness, it can be deactivated.  Although users can still navigate to deactivated accounts, most other functionality within them is disabled.

The main focus of our account page is to display all the interactions within your account.  One choice is to place the deactivation function at the bottom of our account the page, below all the records of interactions. We're talking near the footer at the bottom of the usable screen height. Users with accounts with many records would need to scroll all the way to the bottom to find this function.

After using the account for some time, it is natural that the account would have many records and this function would be pushed pretty far down the page.  Probably 4 or more viewport heights.

Another choice is to place deactivate where users would not have to scroll to find it.  Perhaps in a menu spawned by clicking on a gear icon, or just a dim button near the account details at the top of the page. Suggestions have been made that it's valuable to assure users do not have to hunt for such a function when it's needed.

We've also seen deactivate/delete/pause account functions placed toward the bottom of an account page before as in the 37 Signals basecamp tool and hidden behind configuration icons in Google tools, opposite examples.

Here are some facts about our function's deactivate behavior:
1) To reverse this action requires the help of tech-support
2) We expect the function to be used only once, at the end of this interface's useful life

Is there an accepted practice or design pattern for the placement of such a function of consequence like "disable/deactivate account"?

I've included a sample of what we're using now down below for clarity.[image: sample of current disable statement at the bottom of the page]

Answer (score 3):

### Most users feel that they should be allowed to easily change their minds

If many users are asking for this then go ahead and move it up top but given what you said about how *rare* and *permanent* this action is I would leave it in a section at the bottom that clearly signifies how permanent this action is...

[image]

You could also add a non-prominent link up top "Need to deactivate the selected accounts?" that instantly scrolls to this bottom section to help users find it but just make sure it is clear to them that doing this action will mean a support call if they change their mind.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I updated the post to show you what we have currently as a message at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I think that is perfect.  Given how permanent this action is there needs to be some sort of confirmation in case of accidental click.  I wouldn't move it to the top and just let people scroll to find it.